# Extract the string between Quotes of particular occurrence in unix

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk, grep

Input file

```
..
set name "old name"; # comment "should be updated"
..
```

Output file

```
..
set name "new name" ; #comment "should be updated"
..
```

when i  tried to  grep the content between quotes with   `grep -i 'name' inputfile | grep -P \".+{\"}`  its grepping content between first " and last "

i.e   `old name"; # comment "should be updated`

any idea to accomplish that using `grep`, `sed` or `awk`!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do. For one thing, your `grep` command includes a curly brace and the input doesn't. Also, it appears that you want to make a substitution based on a comparison of your input and output.

However, taking your question literally, here's how you can `grep` the strings between the quotes. You can use non-greedy matching:

```
grep -Po '".*?"'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'set name "username"; # comment "should be updated"' | grep -Po '".*?"'
"username"
"should be updated"
```

**Edit:**

In order to substitute a value, you can use `sed`. You would not use `grep`.

```
sed 's/"[^"]*"/"new name"/'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'set name "old name"; # comment "should be updated"' | sed 's/"[^"]*"/"new name"/'
set name "new name"; # comment "should be updated"
```

Comment: Thanks, its helpful,   now updated my question, hope it was clear now,  if we pipe the output of grep to sed/awk, with what varaible we can access that! so that we can replace the output of grep with other string and write back

Comment: @user1228191, note the technique used to achieve non-greedy matching: a quote, then as many non-quote characters as possible, then another quote (`"[^"]*"`)

Answer (score 8):

Sed:

```
sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

Awk:

```
awk -F'"' '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: Thanks so much , can we re-direct that grepped output for replacement, sorry i'm a newbie, just learning things!

Comment: what i mean is if we pipe the output of grep to sed/awk,  with what varaible we can access that!

Answer (score 1):

I assume the word after `should be` is supposed to be the new username

```
sed 's/^\([^"]\+"\)[^"]\+\(.*should be \)\([^"]\+\)/\1\3\2\3/'
```

a little tidier with GNU sed

```
sed -r 's/^([^"]+")[^"]+(.*should be )([^"]+)/\1\3\2\3/'
```

**Edit** - Dennis has a good answer. If the new name is held in a shell variable, you can use a quoting trick:

```
new_name="Fred"
sed 's/"[^"]*/"'"$new_name"'"/'
```

Comment: sorry, its my fault, i didn't mean that..new username can be anything.. thanks for answering

Comment: if we pipe the output of grep to sed/awk, with what varaible we can access that!

Comment: You could instead use double quotes for the outer set: `sed "s/\"[^\"]*\"/\"$new_name\"/"`. However, in replacing the hairy quoting, you're left with lots of hairy escaping and you'd have to be careful to escape some instances of `$`. You could use octal escapes (`\o42` - letter "o" believe it or not) for versions of `sed` that support it, but in this case I don't think it's any better. By the way, you're missing a double quote before the second slash.